# Look ahead in a for loop iterating through a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple for loop iterating through a user input string. If the it encounters a certain value, I want to be able to look ahead at the next value in order to determine what to do next. What is the best way to accomplish this? For example in my code below, if it encounters a "1" in the string, it should look at the next character in the string. If it is also a 1, print 1. Otherwise do nothing.

```
UserInput = input("Enter calculator expression:")

for x in UserInput:
    ...
    ...
    if x == 1:
#       if the next value in the string is 1:
#           print 1
#       else:
#       do nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use range and len in the loop to get position address

```
UserInput = input("Enter calculator expression")

for i in range(len(UserInput)-1):
    if x[i]=='1':
        if x[i+1]=='1':
            print "something"
        else:
             pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You can zip a string with itself, but offset with a slice.

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> the_input = 'foobar'  # example
>>> the_input[1:]  # slice off the first character
'oobar'
>>> for c, lookahead in zip_longest(the_input, the_input[1:]):
...   print(c, lookahead)
...
f o
o o
o b
b a
a r
r None
```

This is more Pythonic than using an index like you would in a language like C.
Zipping pairs things elementwise, like the teeth of a zipper.

Comment: readability matters too. Looks like the user who posted this is a beginner. You should provide solution at the novice level.

Comment: "Easy" is not the same as "familiar". "Novice level" does not mean "the most like C" (i.e. unpythonic). Fiddling with indexes is very error-prone, and not at all what I would recommend for beginners. Zipping is more reliable, and therefore "easier" to get right.

Comment: Let them make errors. Then they will look for more reliable solutions and learn from their mistakes. That's the learning curve. If you bombard them with itertools, zip_longest, array slicing all at the same time, they will be discouraged soon. Let them take time and learn

Comment: More than just beginners read these answers. Every beginner introduction to Python I've seen already covers slicing. `itertools` is just where I imported `zip_longest()` from, and it's trivial to understand if you've ever used the builtin `zip()`. So really, I'm "bombarding" them with *one* thing. Maybe half a thing if they've ever touched `zip()`, which is no more obscure than the `enumerate()` builtin I saw in the other answer.

Comment: Well you definitely seemed to have scared the person off, I can't find even a single comment from him/ her. Well hope you are happy now

Answer (score 2):

A different (probably more pythonic) way of doing this with the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
for char, next_char in zip(UserInput, UserInput[1:]):
    if char == "1" and char == next_char:
        print(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user enumerate() function.
something like this,

```
#!/user/bin/python3
for i,x in enumerate(UserInput):
    if x=='1':
        if UserInput[i+1] == '1':
            print('1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, python convention is snake-case (user_input instead)

code below is my solution

```py
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result

pair = list(window(user_input))
comparison_list = ["1"]
result = [x for x,y in pair if x in comparison_list and x == y]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to look ahead. At least it is not what we usually do when we tackle this kind of problem. Instead, you should look backward - by storing the information. The following example stores the information in a variable `state` and you can decide the next action in the subsequent iteration.

```
UserInput = input("Enter calculator expression:")

state = '0'
for x in UserInput:
    if x == '1':
        if state == '1':
            print('1')
        else:
            state = '1'
    else:
        state = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prev_char = None
for char in input("Enter calculator expression:"):
    pass  # Here you can check the current character and the previous character
    if 1 == prev_char and 1 == char:
        print(1)
    prev_char = char
```